# sorted vector of pair (std::vector<pair<int, int>>) Search by first element of pair and update the second element value

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14, c++17

I have a Vector of pairs (std::vector<pair<int, int>>)  with sorted order by first of pair. I wanna update the second value of the pair by searching the first value of the pair.

```
vector<pair<int,int>> v = { {1, 5}, {4, 26}, {5, 3}, {7, 13}, {12, 43}, {17, 31} };
```

I would like to update the second value of the pair as 27 which has a first value 12.

```
// Expected v
v = { {1, 5}, {4, 26}, {5, 3}, {7, 13}, {12, 27}, {17, 31} }
```

Remember that vector was already sorted by the first element of pair.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Use boost::flat_map.

Comment: Do a binary search and then update the found element,

Comment: ... and don't mix c++ versions when compiling. It can get confusing. Select one ...

Comment: Looks like a sound plan. Go for it, and let us know when you have a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a binary search on a sorted vector using [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). The result is the iterator to the first element greater or equal than the argument. You have to manually compare the result for an exact match.

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), std::make_pair(12, 0));
if (it != v.end() && it->first == 12) {
  it->second = 27;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use std::map

```
std::map<int, int> mymap;
mymap = { {1, 5}, {4, 26}, {5, 3}, {7, 13}, {12, 27}, {17, 31} };
int newValue = 5;
mymap.at(12) = newValue; //update the value 27 here
std::cout << mymap.at(12) << std::endl;
```

Note that `at` function will throw an `out of range exception` if requested element is missing from map.
Also, like your vector, this map is sorted.