# Why can't I access a std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> through vec[i].first()?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am attempting to print data from a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>` via a `for` loop. MSVC says that I can't call make a call through this vector. I tried it with `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` as well and got the same error. I tried iterating with a `for` loop on a `std::vector<int>` and it worked fine.  I haven't tried on another compiler.

Sample code

```
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> header_data = get_png_header_data(file_contents);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < header_data.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << header_data[i].first(); //throws an error on this line "call of an object of a class type without an appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type
    }
```

I would appreciate an alternative way to access my vector or another storage type that I could use.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62583770/2115408) for usage

Comment: `.first` is a data member of the pair object, not a function.

Comment: `header_data[i].first()` treats `header_data[i].first` as if it is a function (or a function object with an `operator()`), and calls it with no arguments.   The error is because the member `first` of a `std::pair` cannot be used like a function.   Remove the `()`.

Comment: @Peter • `std::pair<std::function(void()), std::function(void())>` could use `p.first()` as a function.  It's not a `first` problem, it's a `is the type first holds invocable?` problem.

Comment: @Elijay - Not in the OP's case, where the members are `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `std::pair` is basically (in a manner of speaking):

```
    struct std::pair {
        std::string first;
        std::string second;
    };
```

That's what `std::pair`s are. `first` and `second` are ordinary class members, not methods/functions. Now you can easily see what's happening: `.first()` attempts to call `first`'s `()` operator overload. Obviously, `std::string`s have no such overloads. That's what your C++ compiler's error message is telling you. If you reread your compiler's error message it now becomes crystal clear.

You obviously meant to write `std::cout << header_data[i].first;`.

Comment: I feel dumb. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, I will accept it in 7 minutes when I can.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated and hardest to learn general purpose programming language in the world today. You are not the first, and you will not be the last to get confused by a compiler's error message. Everyone goes through that phase, at some point. It's perfectly normal. You would ordinarily expect an error message to say something like "first is not a function". But C++ is just too complicated. `first` could be a class with a perfectly usable `()` overload, so in that case what you were trying to do might actually compile.

Comment: *Everyone goes through that phase, at some point.*  That phase starts on day 1 of programming in C++, and continues on until the last day.  Even my co-workers & former co-workers who are very experienced in C++ make those kinds of mistakes, such as Alex Stepanov and Scott Meyers.